# Radio button when clicked to show what is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm using reactjs chartjs 2 to create some charts. I have a radio button as you can see of two values of Line and Bar. When one is clicked I want it to show the one that is clicked and when the other one is clicked show that one. But it is not working out, anyone might have a clue?

````js
        <div>
          <label>Choose your chart sample:</label>
          <label>Line Chart
            <input
              value="Line"
              name="Line"
              type="radio"
              checked={"Line" === this.state.chartOption}
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({chartOption: e.target.value})
              }}
              />
          </label>
          <label>Bar Chart
            <input
              value="Bar"
              name="Bar"
              type="radio"
              checked={"Bar" === this.state.chartOption}
              onChange={e => {
                this.setState({chartOption: e.target.value})
              }}
              />
          </label>
        </div>
        
        <this.state.chartOption data={data} />
    ```
````

Comment: Hi there, can you please give me more details, do you want to have only one radio button checked at the time? What's your problem specifically, I mean what's not working out?

Comment: @abalexandre The chart is not showing.